# ¿Como obtener la ubicación interna de un producto? Odoo v15

Tags: python, odoo

Estoy trabajando en algunas modificaciones para el formulario del modelo **stock_picking**, actualmente tengo varias ubicaciones configuradas en almacén tales como BD-0001, BD-0002, etc. De igual forma para este caso estoy usando un producto que ya tiene 60 existencias en el almacén **BD-0001**.

La ubicación la estoy intentando obtener de dos formas desde esta función, una es usando el parametro `self.env[stock_move_line].search`, `write` y `self.env.cr.commit()`

```
def _display_brand(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        so_name = str(self.origin)  # --- Recuperamos nombre de la Orden de Venta asociada al Picking
        _logger.info('SO NAME %s', so_name)

        move_line_ids = self.move_line_ids  # Puede dar como resultado una lista [1098462] o [1098462,1098462 ]
        if move_line_ids:
            _logger.info('move_line_ids %s, id:%s, movimiento: %s ', move_line_ids, self.id, self.name)
            move_line_id = move_line_ids[0].id
            _logger.info('MOVE LINE ID %s', move_line_id)

            #Recupera la ubicación interna del producto
            stock_location_id = self.env['stock.move.line'].search([['id', '=', move_line_id]]).location_id
            _logger.info('STOCK LOCATION ID:  %s', stock_location_id.complete_name)
            _logger.info('STOCK LOCATION ID:  %s', stock_location_id.id)
            self.ubicacion_origen = stock_location_id.id
            picking = self.env['stock.picking'].search([('id', '=', self.id)])
            resultado = picking.write({'ubicacion_origen': stock_location_id.id})
            _logger.info('RESULTADO:  %s', resultado)
            self.env.cr.commit()
        else:
            self.ubicacion_origen = ''
            self.brand = ''
```

La otra es asignando directamente al campo destino tal como `self.ubicacion_origen = stock_location_id.id`

```
def _display_brand(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        so_name = str(self.origin)  # --- Recuperamos nombre de la Orden de Venta asociada al Picking
        _logger.info('SO NAME %s', so_name)

        move_line_ids = self.move_line_ids  # Puede dar como resultado una lista [1098462] o [1098462,1098462 ]
        if move_line_ids:
            _logger.info('move_line_ids %s, id:%s, movimiento: %s ', move_line_ids, self.id, self.name)
            move_line_id = move_line_ids[0].id
            _logger.info('MOVE LINE ID %s', move_line_id)

            #Recupera la ubicación interna del producto
            stock_location_id = self.env['stock.move.line'].search([['id', '=', move_line_id]]).location_id
            _logger.info('STOCK LOCATION ID:  %s', stock_location_id.complete_name)
            _logger.info('STOCK LOCATION ID:  %s', stock_location_id.id)
            self.ubicacion_origen = stock_location_id.id
        else:
            self.ubicacion_origen = ''
            self.brand = ''
```

Sin embargo durante la ejecución me aparece el siguiente error, lo cual al principio pensé que era porque me faltaba el `else` de la sentencia `if`, lo agregué pero no cambió nada. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 886, in get
    return field_cache[record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 17629
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1057, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 889, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'stock.picking(17629,).dsp_etiqueta_meli'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 886, in get
    return field_cache[record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 17629
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1110, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 889, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'stock.picking(17629,).dsp_etiqueta_meli'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 916, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1343, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1335, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 464, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\models.py", line 3227, in read
    return self._read_format(fnames=fields, load=load)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\models.py", line 3247, in _read_format
    vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\models.py", line 5888, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1113, in __get__
    raise ValueError("Compute method failed to assign %s.%s" % (record, self.name))
Exception
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Odoo 15e\server\odoo\http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Compute method failed to assign stock.picking(17629,).dsp_etiqueta_meli
2022-09-10 18:28:51,451 12864 INFO yuju werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2022 18:28:51] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/stock.picking/read HTTP/1.1" 200 - 100 0.102 0.110
```

Comment: Hola, encontraste el error? Al parecer es un error con uno de los valores relacionados al calcular un método computado a dsp_etiqueta_meli. Parece que no devuelve el valor, si no la función.

Comment: Hola @Legna, me vi en la necesidad de sustituir la función por un proceso que viene por defecto en Odoo 15 y modificar el almacén como _traslado interno_ para que me  aparezcan la ubicación origen y ubicación destino, dado que no encontré otra forma de hacerlo